# Value of request parameters from with callback?

Tags: node.js, express

I am using the `express.js` framework on `node.js`. I am trying to get the value of the first string argument from `app.get()` from within the callback.

```
app.get('/example/code', function(req,res){
 console.log(firstParam); // "/example/code"
});

app.get('/example/:id', function(req,res){
 console.log(firstParam); // "/example/:id"
});

app.get('/example(s?)', function(req,res){
 console.log(firstParam); // "/example(s?)"
});
```

Any way to do this? As you can see I don't want the url exactly, I want what the factor for the route was. For the second example I DO NOT WANT to return `/example/2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the path inside the callback with:

```
req.route.path
```

Among other info out of `req.route`:

```
{ path: '/example/:id',
  method: 'get',
  callbacks: [ [Function] ],
  keys: [ { name: 'id', optional: false } ],
  regexp: /^\/example\/(?:([^\/]+?))\/?$/i,
  params: [ id: '42' ] }
```

Comment: I posted it in [github](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/1253) as an issue and got a reply really quickly. `req.route.path` works. Thanks for your submission.