# Get route definition in middleware

Tags: node.js, express

Does anyone know if it's possible to get the path used to trigger the route?

For example, let's say I have this:

```
app.get('/user/:id', function(req, res) {});
```

With the following simple middleware being used

```
function(req, res, next) {
     req.?
});
```

I'd want to be able to get `/user/:id` within the middleware, this is not `req.url`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Value of request parameters from with callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752124/value-of-request-parameters-from-with-callback)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

What you want is `req.route.path`.

For example:

```
app.get('/user/:id?', function(req, res){
  console.log(req.route);
});

// outputs something like

{ path: '/user/:id?',
  method: 'get',
  callbacks: [ [Function] ],
  keys: [ { name: 'id', optional: true } ],
  regexp: /^\/user(?:\/([^\/]+?))?\/?$/i,
  params: [ id: '12' ] }
```

http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.route

---

**EDIT:**

As explained in the comments, getting `req.route` in a middleware is difficult/hacky. The router middleware is the one that populates the `req.route` object, and it probably is in a lower level than the middleware you're developing.

This way, getting `req.route` is only possible if you hook into the router middleware to parse the `req` for you before it's executed by Express itself.

Comment: That would be perfect, but it doesn't seem to work when using middleware.  I can get the object from within the route itself, but if I'm using middleware and trigger the route, it's `undefined`

Comment: Ah, sorry. I simply missed the part 'in middleware' in your title. Well, if your middleware is in a higher level than the express router (what probably is the case), you will not have how to retrieve the parsed route, because this will be done by the router.

Comment: I've added the explanation of the comment into the answer aswell, for anyone looking forward into this question

Comment: A possible solution to the racing condition would be hooking into an Express specific event like `res.on('before render')`, if such an event existed. Do you know anything related to this?

Comment: As I'm no longer an active Express user, such thing MAY exist nowadays, but if it isn't documented, just don't go this way, otherwise it may break when updates come

Answer (score 15):

FWIW, two other options:

```
// this will only be called *after* the request has been handled
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.on('finish', function() {
    console.log('R', req.route);
  });
  next();
});

// use the middleware on specific requests only
var middleware = function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('R', req.route);
  next();
};
app.get('/user/:id?', middleware, function(req, res) { ... });
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a little late, but for later Express/Node setups `req.originalUrl` works just fine!

Hope this helps

Comment: if the route definition is `/user/:id` , the `req.originalUrl` returns the "evaluated" route like `/user/1000` https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.originalUrl The question is for the route definition

Answer (score 2):

This nasty trick using prototype override will help

```
   "use strict"
    var Route = require("express").Route;

    module.exports = function () {
        let defaultImplementation = Route.prototype.dispatch;

        Route.prototype.dispatch = function handle(req, res, next) {
            someMethod(req, res); //req.route is available here
            defaultImplementation.call(this, req, res, next);
        };
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

`req.route.path` will work to get the path for the given route. But if you want the complete path including the path of the parent route, use something like

```
let full_path = req.baseUrl+req.route.path;
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at Router().stack, which has all the routes defined. In your middleware you need to manually compare the available routes with the one called to define actions.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).