# Why would my express router middleware not have req.route defined?

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to use router middleware to get the value of [req.route](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.route). I have some simple code like this:

**server.js**

```js
import api from './api';
// ...
app.use('/api/', api);
```

**api/index.js**

```js
Object.keys(routes).forEach(key => {
  router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('++++++++++++++++++');
    console.log(req.route);
    console.log('++++++++++++++++++');

    next();
  });
  // so localhost:8080/api/currentkey works
  router.use(`/${key}`, routes[key]);
});
```

When I hit `/api/currentkey`, `req.route` is undefined. If I move the middleware after the route definition (instead of before), it doesn't seem to fire at all.

My router objects are all setup using a method like this:

```js
import express from 'express';
import asyncify from 'express-asyncify';

export default function() {
  return asyncify(express.Router());
}
```

I saw a solution using events on [Get route definition in middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460481/get-route-definition-in-middleware), but am wondering why that is required vs what I have done here. I'm also not sure the way it's written would make things accurate (such as changing a transaction name for new relic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's right. `req.route` is available *only* in your *final* `route`. From the docs:

> Contains the **currently-matched** route, a string

Note the words in **bold**, Your middleware where you're logging `req.route` is not a `route`.

So it would be available to say:

```
app.get('/path', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.route);
})
```

Since, `req` object is mutated while passing around `middleware`, you can access `req.route` for the *last* matched `route`. For example:

```
app.get('/path', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send('hello');
  next() // <-- calling next middleware
})

// middleware mounted after the above route
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.route) // outputs the last matched at /path route
})
```

Comment: Why can't I run middleware after the route is matched though? I know error middleware is special, but it certainly runs after the route match. Is that the only case I can do that then?

Comment: You'll have to call `next` in the middleware that was *matched* else express will not proceed to the next middleware. `I know error middleware is special` error middleware is not an exception to that, notice how error middleware is executed only when you call `next(error)`

Comment: Given `router.use(`/${key}`, routes[key]);`, where `routes[key]` is equal to a `Router` with `router.get('/', endpoint);`, I can't really call `next`. a `console.log` would cause an explosion cause headers would have already been sent. not that i'd be using a `console.log` in prod, but it makes me think this would be wrong

Comment: `I can't really call next`, Yes, if you don't want express to execute the next middleware. So now that's making me question, what is it that you're trying to achieve accessing `req.route`?

Comment: Thanks for editing. This lets me write something clearer than my last comment :) Your console.log would fail because it would have happened after headers were sent. That being said, my actual goal is around getting the path for new relic transaction name. I want to have `/path/:id/something` vs `/path/unique-value-each-time/something` So it's likely the `console.log` issue is a non-issue, just makes some debugging harder

Comment: `Your console.log would fail because it would have happened after headers were sent.` Actually it won't. :) Am not sending headers again, remember am just logging on my server

Comment: weird, i get that error. i must be doing something else wrong. will dig more :) thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193726/discussion-between-dave-stein-and-1556089774).

Answer (score 0):

Was having the same issue. Found that you can use `app.all` and will always have access to req.route this way.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like ::

It works perfectly in koa but not sure in express::

```
app.use(async (req, res, next)=> {
  // Do your work
  await next(); // This will work fine, wait for next route/middleware
});

app.get('/path', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send('hello');
  next() 
})
```