# Why can't i call `next` after a route runs in express?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a simple route like this:

```js
// This is just a health check
const endpoint = (req, res, next) => {
  res.json({
    status: 'ok',
  });
  next();
};

router.get('/', endpoint);
```

I get `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.` from express. This is even if I have no other possible middleware to run next, or if my `next` middleware does literally nothing and is an empty function.

What am I missing about the way middleware and `next` works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be a couple of issues:

You've a `404` handler at the end (we all do) and have simply overlooked. For example:

```
app.get('/path', (req, res, next) => {
  res.json({ greet: "Welcome!" })
  next() // <-- calling next middleware
})

// set up a 404 handler at the end
app.use((req, res) => {
  res.status(404).send('Opps! Not Found');
})
```

This would result in error `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.` Because your 404 handler is sending a response.

**Or** You've stumbled across an *unknown feature* (Or plainly, one of your route is not working as expected, possibly design error). Consider the following route:

```
app.get('/path/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  res.json({ message: "Welcome!" });
  next() // <-- calling next middleware
})

app.get('/path/test', (req, res, next) => {
  res.json({ message: "Welcome!" });
})
```

Calling `next` in `/path/:id` route would result in error if your request path is `/path/test` (This would in general suggest for a better routing implementation)

An easy way to understand the `middleware` and `next` is relate to the way `switch` statement works:

```js
function test(x) {
  switch (x) {
    case 'Oranges':
      console.log('Orange juice');
      break;
    case 'Mangoes': // fall through
    case 'Papayas':
      console.log('Pickles');
      break;
    case 'Banana':
      console.log('Milkshake');
      // forgot the break
    case 'Apple':
      console.log('Apple Pie')
      break;
    default:
      console.log('Sorry, no ' + x + '.');
  }
}

test('Banana')
```

Calling `next` is like `fall through` of a `switch` statement, execute the next case too.

So when you call `next` in one route and the `request` goes on to match another `route` (an unintended match) where you're sending response, you'll find yourself smacking your face with the error.

Comment: The 404 was the answer. I have `router.get('*')` to handle the 404s, but same difference here. Great catch.

Comment: PS: I am going to switch the 404 to a middleware and make sure it runs after what I am trying to do now. Breaking it out will fix things up

Answer (score 0):

I think you answered it in your own question: you cannot do anything to a response after it has already been sent. And if you think about it, this kind of makes sense. If `next` is used to modify the request in some way, why would it still "act" like it is "working" after the request has already been sent?

According to the [Express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html), here is how they use `next` within a `get` request:

```js
app.get('/example/b', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('the response will be sent by the next function ...')
  next()
}, function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello from B!')
})
```

Comment: I am hoping to take some data after the fact and make an xhr request. Would that even count as manipulating the response? I understand it erroring if I try to call res.send or something like that again, but not just an empty method. But you're saying this is the way it's supposed to be eh?

Comment: Ahh! It sounds like you are trying to use `next` in a way it was not intended to be used. What do you mean by "take some data after the fact?"

Comment: This question is a followup to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56243480/why-would-my-express-router-middleware-not-have-req-route-defined/56244021, where an answer made it seem like I can do this. My actual desire to be able to look at either: `req.path & req.params` or `req.route`. The second option doesn't seem doable without some significant hacking. I would take this data to set proper transaction name in new relic

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do something else in that particular endpoint, the correct way would be doing it before sending the response. Its the way the architecture of express works.

If you want to apply the same logic to every endpoint (looks like so, since you want to check `req.path`, `req.params` and/or `req.route`), you can use a middleware to listen to the `finish` event of express:

```
router.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.on('finish', function() {
    // extra logic here after sending response
  });
  next();
});

const endpoint = (req, res, next) => {
  res.json({
    status: 'ok',
  });
};

router.get('/', endpoint);
```

Comment: Do you know that it will execute before the connection is cut? ie if I curl to an endpoint, would the `finish` logic fire before I get a response?

Comment: The finish middleware should be executed after the connection is cut. For example, it you throw an error in the `extra logic` line, the client wont receive any error.

Comment: Yeah, that would be an issue for me given that I want to use this to set a transaction name for New Relic based on the req.route.

Comment: I see. The lifecycle of a request in express ends with `res.json()`/`res.send()`. You could pass the response to a new final middleware at `req.response` and do some logic between.