# How to get the route of a request in Express.js for static resources?

Tags: node.js, express, static-files

I want to get the url `/view/:id` quite similar like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460481/get-route-definition-in-middleware). The only answer I found satisfying was from HagenAnuth by using `req.originalUrl`. Unfortunately this does not work for static resources.

```
app.use('/view/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.originalUrl); // -> returns js file and not e.g. /view/25
    next();
}, express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));
```

Is there nowadays a good way to do this?

Comment: How about `req.baseUrl + req.path`?

Comment: Thanks @eol I tried `req.baseUrl` together with `req.path` before and it didn't work either (it has returned also the path of the js file). Now I tried it again and now it works perfectly. And also `req.originalUrl` works now as expected. The problem is that I don't think that I did anything other than turn off the PC for 2 hours. Either I changed something unintentionally in the code or `req.baseUrl` and  `req.originalUrl` are unstable. I will look for the behaviour in next days and comment here again.

Comment: Okay, seems that the problem was somewhere on my side. The code runs perfect since last week and the problem does not occur anymore. I always receive now the desired route.